# Allow file access to specific users in Drupal (not roles)

Tags: users, files

I have historical data recorded in pdf files for our clients. Now I am developing a website (in Drupal) from where clients should be able to access this data. The problem is that i don't want this files to be available to anyone else than the user to whom the information belongs.

Since this data is periodically recorded I could store it in a specific folder for each user.
My question is that if it's possible to give access to this folders or its content to specific users in Drupal. Because the alternative would be to create a Role for every user which is not good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I found a solution that covers all my needs. I created a custom page template for the page from where i want to access the files (ex. node--4.tpl.php) that catches the username and generates a cookie with it:

```
global $user;
$username = $user->name;
$cookie_name = 'cookie_name';//
$cookie_value = $username;//
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (3600), "/");
```

Then I create a .htaccess file in each user's folder that contains this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !cookiename=username [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://alternativepath/ [L]
```

So only the user who's username is like the username i ask for in the htaccess can access the folder. In my case I ask for another field, not the username, but this should be enough as a simple example.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new **content type** and add fields according to your
   requirement or [user reference field](https://drupalize.me/videos/adding-user-reference-field?p=1166)
2. Disable its Front page publish option.
3. Create new user **Role** like "client".
4. Create view of files and add **relationship or contentuxal filter**
   against user loggin id.
5. Create **block view** assign this block into specific region.

Comment: would it make te files unavailable to access for other users?

Comment: yes due to only login user can view their own file